# ¿Como eliminar un elemento agregado por el metodo append de acuerdo a la opcion seleccionada de un select multiple?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

el problema es  :

- Tengo un select multiple que lista registros de una tabla, entonces cuando selecciono una opcion del select  me agrega un input con el ID del usuario dentro de un DIV, y cuando deselecciono una opcion sigue agregando uno nuevo input .
- ¿Como puedo evitar que siga agregando cuando deselecciono una opcion y que me muestre los input segun la cantidad  de opciones seleccionadas ?

```js
$("#paginas").on('click', function() {
  var count = $(".opcion :selected option").length;
  var idUsuarios = $("#txtIdUsuarios").val();
  var add = "";

  add += '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuarios[]" value="' + idUsuarios + '">';
  $("#contiene").append(add);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="" id="modalAddPermiso" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Asignación de Permisos por Paginas</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="form_permiso" action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Usuario</label>
              <input type="text" id="txtIdUsuarios" value="2">
              <input type="text" id="nomUsuario" name="nomUsuario" value="Juan Perez" class="form-control" disabled="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Rol </label>
              <input type="text" id="nombrerol" name="nombrerol" class="form-control" disabled="" value="Gerente">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="paginas[]" id="paginas" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="height: 300px;">

                
                  <option class="opcion" value="1">Pagina1</option>
                
                  <option  class="opcion" value="2">Pagina2</option>
                
                  <option  class="opcion" value="3">Pagina3</option>
                
                  <option  class="opcion" value="4">Pagina4</option>
                
                  <option class="opcion" value="5">Pagina5</option>
                
                  <option class="opcion" value="6">Pagina6</option>
               

              </select>
            </div>
            <div id="contiene" class="col-md-12"></div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="btnsavepermiso">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cuando mencionas que deseleccionas la opción a que te refieres, elijes otra opción con un valor nulo o que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con un evento `change` primero limpiamos el `div` contenedor, así evitamos la duplicidad datos, después recorreremos el select para ver que opciones se tienen seleccionadas y poder agregar solo lo que se desee. El código quedaría así:

```
$( "#paginas" ).change(function() {

        $("#contiene").empty();
        $( "#paginas option:selected" ).each(function() {
            var str = "";
            str += $( this ).val();
            add = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuarios_'+str+'" value="' + idUsuarios + '">';
            $("#contiene").append(add);

        });

    });
```

Espero te sirva.